# Asp.NET Core How to set maxJsonLength

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

As we know how to set maxJsonLength in web.config in ASP.NET MVC but what about in .NET Core?

I'm facing this error while posting a large json object on line # 4 right after PostAsync.

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property

**Code snippet:**

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rvd);
var content = new StringContent(jsonString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var result  = await client.PostAsync(returnUrl, content);
var temp = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just how big is your JSON ?

Comment: Around 2.5MB...

Comment: What is the response from the API? Is it sending you back your object?

Comment: Nothing. Response doesn't matter. I wan't to post this data and have some processing on it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchema_MaximumLength.htm) the maximum length is the size of a signed int (around 2GB).

Comment: Plus 1. Perhaps you are right, actually I'm getting this error on line # 4. Right after PostAsync method.

Comment: That's the maximum length *that you can set*, not the default max length. Doesn't answer the question.